# Spring Boot addResourceHandler does not word until rename files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I work on intellij ultimate 2019.3 and I added Tomcat 9.0.33 as my server for my SpringBoot application. Fedora 31.
I am following the tutorial of pluralsight "Spring Framework: Spring MVC Fundamentals" and I am at chapter 6 "Resolve static files".

So the problem is that I added those lines

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdf/");
    }
```

and I drag and drop a pdf file in my /WEB-INF/pdf/ directory.
When I started my app and tried to open it at http://localhost:8080/pluralsightmvc/files/pdf/mypdf.pdf 
it gave me an error 404 page

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /pluralsightmvc/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
```

If I rename the pdf (inside intellij or in my file browser) and restart the app it will work with no problem.
http://localhost:8080/pluralsightmvc/files/pdf/myRenamedPdf.pdf

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: where exactly does your WEB-INF folder under your project? I mean what is the absolute path of it?

Comment: Looks like there is similar issue reported on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235675

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK Absolute path is /home/user/Documents/IdeaProjects/pluralsightmvc/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

Comment: @y.bedrov yes it looks like my problem.